# YDACF using data-value?

Tags: yadcf

Currently I am yadcf on the following DOM node:

```
<a data-csrf="" data-pk="2031" data-role="x-editable" data-step="any" data-type="text" data-url="./ajax/update/" data-value="0" href="#" id="remaining_account_budget" name="remaining_account_budget" class="editable editable-click editable-empty">Empty</a>
```

with the following options:

```
column_data_type: "html"
column_number:7
filter_type:"range_number"
html_data_type:"value"
```

Is there a way to tell yadcf to use the value in data-value instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`html5_data`](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/39c1af7e179993ca9c2189fc16b41df95dada96d/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L101) feature of yadcf

```
column_number:7,
filter_type:"range_number",
html5_data: "data-filter"
```

> - html5_data  Required:           false   Type:               String  Default value:      undefined   Possible values:    data-filter /
>     data-search / anything that is supported by datatables    Description:
>     Allows to filter based on data-filter / data-search attributes of the
>      element, read more:
>     http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Take a look at the yadcf docs :)